# La extensión Quokka.js me manda este error en visula studio code " You may use the "node" setting to configure the location of node." que hago

Tags: javascript, nodejs, vscode

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Apenas estoy empezando nose si sera un error grave, les agradezco su conocimiento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tuve el mismo problema lo solucione: instalando nodejs y npm en el sistema operativo yo ocupo ubuntu
sudo apt-get install nodejs npm

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/341876)